When is a classical field theory on curved spacetime supersymmetric?
Our setup is a classical field theory which is defined on any (generally curved) spacetime $(M,g)$. For Minkowski spacetime $\mathbb{R}^{1,n-1}$, the theory is invariant under the action of a corresponding super Poincaré group $G$. For our purposes, any element in $G$ is of the form $e^{i(a_\mu P^\mu + \omega_{\mu\nu}M^{\mu\nu} + \sum\limits_{i}^\mathcal{N}\theta_\alpha^{(i)} Q^{(i) \alpha})}$, where $Q^{(i)\alpha}$ and $\theta_\alpha^{(i)}$ are in mutually dual spinor representations. I have only included this information to explain why supersymmetry transformations are not a mere action of the super Poincaré algebra, but contain a spinor as a prefactor.
Observation 1: The theory on Minkowski spacetime locally induces a representation of the super Poincaré group on the curved spacetime
Proof:
Fields are sections of vector bundles over $M$. It is thus sufficient to define the induced action on local sections of arbitrary vector bundles $E$ with standard fibre $S$ (The standard fibre is the same in flat and curved spacetime). Let $p \in M$ and $(\varphi, U)$ be a chart containing $p$. Then, $\varphi(U) \subset \mathbb{R}^{1,n-1}$. Now let $(\psi, \tilde U)$ be a bundle chart of $E$ around $p$. Wlog, $U = \tilde U$.
There is a one-to-one correspondence between local sections $s \in \Gamma_U(E)$ and maps $\varphi(U) \to S$. The latter is simply the space of local sections of the corresponding vector bundle in flat spacetime (Any bundle is trivial on flat spacetime) and thus is a representation $\rho$ of $G$. The isomorphism of vector spaces is given by:
$$\Phi: \Gamma_U(E) \to Fun(\varphi(U),S), s \mapsto proj_S\circ\psi \circ s\circ\varphi^{-1}$$
$$\Phi^{-1}: Fun(\varphi(U),S) \to \Gamma_U(E), \sigma \mapsto \psi^{-1}\circ(id_U \times (\sigma\circ\varphi))$$
We can thus define the representation $\tilde \rho(g) := \Phi^{-1}\circ \rho (g) \circ \Phi$ on $\Gamma_U(E)$.
Question 1: Is this construction independent of the choice of charts? The question is equivalent to $\Phi\circ \tilde \Phi^{-1}$ being an intertwiner of $\rho$. The tilde denotes a different choice of charts.
Question 2: When does the induced representation on the local sections define a representation on the space of global sections? Is this how we find out if a theory on curved spacetime is still supersymmetric (Admits a super group action of the super Poincaré group)?
The answer seems to depend on Killing vectors and spinors, as can be seen by this quote from this website:

The theory of gravity is locally Poincaré-symmetric: in first order formulation it is a Poincaré group gauge theory. Nevertheless, any of its solutions – which is a pseudo-Riemannian manifold – may, but need not, have any Poincaré-symmetry. It does have such a global symmetry for every Killing vector on the spacetime. Such may or may not exist. Generically it does not exist.
The analog of these Killing vectors in supergravity are Killing spinors: covariantly constant spinors (sections of a spinor bundle annihilated by the spin connection‘s covariant derivative). For every such, the background has one global supersymmetry transformation. These may or may not exist. Generically they do not.

I am searching for an answer in classical field theory, so sadly, answers similar to the one given here do not help me.

Assume a given field theory with fields $\Phi^I$, where $I$ spans all the fields. $\Phi^I$ can be either a boson or a fermion and have any spin consistent with its statistics. Let the flat-space action be
$$S_\text{flat}=\int \mathrm{d}^d x\mathcal{L}(\Phi^I,\partial_\mu\Phi^I).$$
Assume it is invariant under given supersymmetry $\delta_Q\Phi^I=\varepsilon\cdot\delta\Phi^I$, where $\varepsilon$ is a fermionic ($x$-independent) spinor. This implies
$$\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta\Phi^I}\cdot\delta\Phi^I+\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta\partial_\mu\Phi^I}\cdot\delta\partial_\mu\Phi^I = \text{Total}\;\text{derivative}.\tag{2}$$
Note that we could commute $\varepsilon$ past the derivative because it is constant. Now let us "put" this action in curved space by covariantizing it
$$S_\text{curved}=\int \mathrm{d}^d x\sqrt{-g}\mathcal{L}(\Phi^I,\nabla_\mu\Phi^I),$$
and perform the same SUSY transformation (now allowing $\varepsilon$ to depend on $x$)
$$\delta_Q S_\text{curved}=\int \mathrm{d}^dx\sqrt{-g}\bigg(\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta\Phi^I}\varepsilon\cdot\delta\Phi^I+\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta\nabla_\mu\Phi^I}\varepsilon\cdot\delta\nabla_\mu\Phi^I+\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta\nabla_\mu\Phi^I}\nabla_\mu(\varepsilon)\delta\Phi^I\bigg).$$
Now, from eq. (2), it is direct to see that
$$\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta\Phi^I}\cdot\delta\Phi^I+\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta\nabla_\mu\Phi^I}\cdot\delta\nabla_\mu\Phi^I=\text{Total}\;\text{covariant}\;\text{derivative}$$
and the first two factors in $\delta_Q S_\text{curved}$ vanish. Thus, the field theory in curved space is supersymmetric if
$$\nabla_\mu \varepsilon=0\tag{3}$$
and there are as many supersymmetries as there are independent covariantly constant spinors in space-time (the Killing spinors). Equation (3) is the Killing spinor equation. The derivation easily generalizes in the case with higher derivative terms.

Thank you for your answer! I think my problem is understanding why $\epsilon$ should be a spinor field all of the sudden. It is after all only an element of the super Poincaré algebra whose odd part is a spinor representation. Of course, we talk about a representation of it, so $\epsilon \in Aut(\Gamma(E))$, where $\Gamma(E)$ is the "space of fields". Could you help me to see the connection, preferably in connection to my assertions in Observation 1?

Being as naive as possible, I would say $\varepsilon$ should be a spinor field because if it is not, the curved space action would clearly be non-invariant under the symmetry. But that's probably not the answer you're looking for. I will try to come up with something better and tell you if I do.  Anyway, I suspect your question would also hold for the usual bosonic case in which you have Lorentz symmetry in tangent space but not globally in curved space. The global symmetries are generated by Killing vectors. The situation should be analogous if you generalize this to the supersymmetric case.

You are absolutely right. Do you happen to know of a book that deals with Killing vectors as generators of global Poincaré symmetries? Thank you very much for taking the time to answer me!

The global symmetries will not necessarily be Poincaré (this will only be the case in Minkowski space, almost by definition). In d=4 Schwarzschild you have SO(3), for instance. I should say this also generalizes to the supersymmetric case. Take type IIB supergravity in 10D as an example. In flat-space you have D=10 N=2 superpoincaré symmetry. The same theory in $AdS_5\times S^5$ also has supersymmetries but the associated group is not superpoincaré, it is PSU(2,2|4) (which turns out to be the d=4 N=4 superconformal group).

I don't have a specific book in mind right now, but anything that discusses isometries in the context of vielbeins (vierbeins, tetrads for 4D) will probably be useful for you. The supersymmetric generalisation would be supervielbeins. If I think of something I'll let you know.
